# HTML <a> tag configuration

Tags: html, format, save, element, prettier

My code looks like this after being saved.

```
<div class="links">
          <a href="#">Forget Password</a><a href="#">Forget Password</a
          ><a href="#">Forget Password</a>
          <a href="#">Signup</a>
        </div>
```

But, which settings (in visual studio code) do I have to change to make it look like this?

```
<div class="links">
          <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
          <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
          <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
          <a href="#">Signup</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Can I ask did u install Prettier?

Comment: It seems to me that your question in related to why your HTML is being jumbled up after you save your code.

This sounds like a setting within your code editor, or a package running locally that would do this. Look in your code editor settings for something like prettier or formatting and you may be able to change some options to prevent this from happening. If you do have a package similar to that of Prettier installed in your project, I suggest you review the documentation of that on their website to understand why this is occurring and fix as required.